# Applet not being uploaded to Eclipse simulator java card

Tags: eclipse, applet, simulation, javacard, cap

please help me . i am learning Javacard programming through this:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javacard/3.1/guide/running-helloworld-sample-command-line.html#GUID-1C5B7DC3-CEB9-4E0C-A45E-56EFD4B0A0AF

running the Hello world Sample: selecting the installer applet returns 0x9000.

But when i run the "create applet" script in eclipse i get SW: 0x6443 (Applet not found).

This is the build console;

```
[build console] 

[ INFO: ] Converting CAP file HelloWorld with target version 3.1.0
[ INFO: ] Verifying CAP file HelloWorld for target version 3.1.0    
[ INFO: ] Generating scripts for CAP file HelloWorld created with target version 3.1.0
[ INFO: ] Converter [v3.1.0]
[ INFO: ]     Copyright (c) 1998, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
    
    
parsing C:\JCSimulator\samples\classic_applets\HelloWorld\applet\bin\com\oracle\jcclassic\samples\helloworld\HelloWorld.class
converting com.oracle.jcclassic.samples.helloworld.HelloWorld
writing C:\JCSimulator\samples\classic_applets\HelloWorld\applet\deliverables\HelloWorld\com\oracle\jcclassic\samples\helloworld\javacard\helloworld.exp
writing C:\JCSimulator\samples\classic_applets\HelloWorld\applet\deliverables\HelloWorld\com\oracle\jcclassic\samples\helloworld\javacard\helloworld.jca
[ INFO: ] conversion completed with 0 errors and 0 warnings.
[ INFO: ]  [v3.1.0] Off-Card Verifier, Version {1}.
[ INFO: ]     Copyright (c) 1998, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
    
    
[ INFO: ] Vï¿½rification du fichier CAP C:\JCSimulator\samples\classic_applets\HelloWorld\applet\deliverables\HelloWorld\com\oracle\jcclassic\samples\helloworld\javacard\helloworld.cap
[ INFO: ] Hash pour com/oracle/jcclassic/samples/helloworld/javacard/ConstantPool.cap       [SHA-256: 7c92a54ccab79f6a406f9f29cc0c6d481f7dbd4d88f2d3fe486fe0c645de0cad]
[ INFO: ] Hash pour com/oracle/jcclassic/samples/helloworld/javacard/Descriptor.cap     [SHA-256: 650cd5d297bc891cb4e979c485d5b48ba418c45bb8ed964f2a8dbc0e056430a2]
[ INFO: ] Hash pour com/oracle/jcclassic/samples/helloworld/javacard/Import.cap     [SHA-256: 8cc3642a6d49023dc39aece31584cf15757e6bbcbc1e299514366eae84efce86]
[ INFO: ] Hash pour com/oracle/jcclassic/samples/helloworld/javacard/Directory.cap      [SHA-256: afc2e67f85122d96911283ee8ee672681a3b923befbcd4b6b58c856d274c8e8c]
[ INFO: ] Hash pour com/oracle/jcclassic/samples/helloworld/javacard/Class.cap      [SHA-256: a0378476e19ce4277b4ddeabcb691c36bb665f0c907c518b00898ee49f7d8427]
[ INFO: ] Hash pour com/oracle/jcclassic/samples/helloworld/javacard/Debug.cap      [SHA-256: ac353feeb5129c18c4b37fb7c871a3b2288d0e75a03442aa71783717bd3b65db]
[ INFO: ] Hash pour com/oracle/jcclassic/samples/helloworld/javacard/Applet.cap     [SHA-256: b4f68c32dc4e40d64552843f48a07a8abbb683a241e94313e5549935cdd2c92d]
[ INFO: ] Hash pour com/oracle/jcclassic/samples/helloworld/javacard/Header.cap     [SHA-256: e955fa336f565699c1a0b26435168973f85f544e8e8009cebac0919e880917ab]
[ INFO: ] Hash pour com/oracle/jcclassic/samples/helloworld/javacard/StaticField.cap        [SHA-256: 5863e9740af5fb905922380b2aa88309a16a285dd3412417ae8af941327901ee]
[ INFO: ] Hash pour com/oracle/jcclassic/samples/helloworld/javacard/Method.cap     [SHA-256: 816f2dd6169aa82e11cd2fd9c4f3a59da737595b2abc347b60e636e0497c7b98]
[ INFO: ] Hash pour com/oracle/jcclassic/samples/helloworld/javacard/RefLocation.cap        [SHA-256: 64daad0cde4dbf12d1bfea1451ddfdf92c12322efcd45856258ce9f8b04d0951]
[ INFO: ] La vï¿½rification est terminï¿½e, 0 avertissements et 0 erreurs.
ScriptGen [v3.1.0]
    Copyright (c) 1998, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
    
    
Missing hash for required component: header.cap
```

My output file:

```
CLA: 00, INS: a4, P1: 04, P2: 00, Lc: 09, a0, 00, 00, 00, 62, 03, 01, 08, 01, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CAP file download section. Output suppressed.
OUTPUT OFF;
OUTPUT ON;
CLA: 80, INS: b8, P1: 00, P2: 00, Lc: 0c, 0a, a0, 00, 00, 00, 62, 03, 01, 0c, 01, 01, 00, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 43
CLA: 00, INS: a4, P1: 04, P2: 00, Lc: 0a, a0, 00, 00, 00, 62, 03, 01, 0c, 01, 01, Le: 00, SW1: 6d, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: 10, P1: 01, P2: 02, Lc: 05, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, Le: 00, SW1: 6d, SW2: 00
```

Expected output provided by the sample:

```
CLA: 00, INS: a4, P1: 04, P2: 00, Lc: 09, a0, 00, 00, 00, 62, 03, 01, 08, 01, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CAP file download section. Output suppressed.
OUTPUT OFF;
OUTPUT ON;
CLA: 80, INS: b8, P1: 00, P2: 00, Lc: 0c, 0a, a0, 00, 00, 00, 62, 03, 01, 0c, 01, 01, 00, Le: 0a, a0, 00, 00, 00, 62, 03, 01, 0c, 01, 01, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 00, INS: a4, P1: 04, P2: 00, Lc: 0a, a0, 00, 00, 00, 62, 03, 01, 0c, 01, 01, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
CLA: 80, INS: 10, P1: 01, P2: 02, Lc: 05, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, Le: 0a, 80, 10, 01, 02, 05, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
```

[Cap file configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jNtG.png).